# How can I access multiple IIS sites with redirects from a mobile device?

Tags: iis

I would like to do some tablet testing on a website I have. The website has two parts, both in separate projects.

Main site:
platform.local.samplesite.com

SSO site:
sso.local.samplesite.com

The issue:
I can access the main website remotely by ip. When redirected to the login, it tries to hit 'sso.local.samplesite.com', and cannot find that remotely, as it only knows the computer ip set to the main platform site.

General navigation would be:
Hit platform -> Get redirected to SSO site -> Sign in -> Get passed back and land on the main page of platform, all logged in

Currently I can hit the main platform site by adding a binding of HTTPS, IP Address all unassigned, using SSL certificate, and no host name. Then, from the mobile device, I hit the computer's IP address. This successfully gets me to the platform page, but then I am redirected and the tablet cannot see sso.local.samplesite.com.

Is there any way for me to have them both bound and successfully redirecting?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would your redirect protocol on sso.local send you to the subsite once login was successful rather than redirecting back to the root site? This in theory would bypass your redirection, assuming you've set the redirection at server level bound to the domain?